# OpenGL-ES mostly transparent textures drawn white

Tags: opengl-es

I am using OpenGL-ES 1.1 for my game. The alpha blending works perfectly fine for me except for when I draw textures which are 99% transparent. For example, if I have a 512x512 image with just a 2px black line in the middle. Such textures are drawn absolutely white on android.

My blending function:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**: This is how I am setting up the textures

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGenTextures(1, &textureCreated);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureCreated);
maOpenGLTexImage2D(image);

// Set texture parameters.
glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterx(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the Android Bitmap class for OpenGL ES textures unless they are completely opaque.  This is because the Bitmap class stores the pixels in pre-multiplied format for Porter-Duff blending, which is not compatible with OpenGL ES blending.  This article gives more detail:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1/

Comment: So what's the way to go about it?

Comment: With native code you don't need the Bitmap class anyway.  With Java, you can call GLES11.glTexImage2D() with the GLES11 wrapper and pass in a ByteBuffer to avoid using GLUtils, PNGDecoder and Bitmap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the code of how i set up gl textures. the function maOpenGLTexImage2D is a mosync sdk function equivalent to glTexImage2D(). Can you tell me how to modify the code? Sorry,I am just learning opengl

Comment: I guess you are using native code then?  I would check the mosync code to see if they use the Bitmap class.  Otherwise, Bitmap should not be a problem.